# Listar valor dos itens do checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Como eu faço para **listar** os valores de checkbox quando o usuário **selecionar** e quando estiver **não selecionado** o valor não aparecer na lista?

```html
<select class="form-control" id="list-lugar">
  <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">-</option>
  <option value="200">1 Shopping</option>
  <option value="200">2 Shopping</option>
  <option value="100">3 Shopping</option>
  <option value="100">4 Plaza</option>
  <option value="100">5 Shopping</option>
  <option value="100">6 Plaza</option>
</select><br><br>

<input id="add-buffet" type="checkbox" value="1000" />
<label>Buffet</label><br>
<input id="add-decoracao" type="checkbox" value="499" />
<label>Decoração</label><br>
<input id="add-foto" type="checkbox" value="800" />
<label>Foto</label><br><br>

<label>Lista</label><br><br>
item 1 R$200,00<br>
item 2 R$1.000,00<br>
item 3 R$499,00<br>
item 4 R$800,00<br>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cara fiz um exemplo aqui parecendo com o que vc quer, mostrando e escondendo as escolhas feitas pelo usuário:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    var inputs = $(this);
    var valor = $(this).val();
    var label = $("label[for='" + $(this).attr('id') + "']").text();
  
      if(inputs.is(":checked") == true) {
        $("#lista").append("<span id='span'> - " + label + " : " + valor + "</span>" );
      } else {
          $("#span").remove();
      }
  });
  $("select").on("change", function() {
    var str = "";
    $("select option:selected").each(function() { 
      str += $(this).text();
    });
    $("#spanSelect").text(str);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" id="list-lugar">
  <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">-</option>
  <option value="200">1 Shopping</option>
  <option value="200">2 Shopping</option>
  <option value="100">3 Shopping</option>
  <option value="100">4 Plaza</option>
  <option value="100">5 Shopping</option>
  <option value="100">6 Plaza</option>
</select><br><br>

<input id="add-buffet" type="checkbox" value="1000" />
<label for="add-buffet">Buffet</label><br>
<input id="add-decoracao" type="checkbox" value="499" />
<label for="add-decoracao">Decoração</label><br>
<input id="add-foto" type="checkbox" value="800" />
<label for="add-foto">Foto</label><br><br>

<label id="lista">Lista</label><br><br>
<span id="spanSelect"></span><br><br>
item 1 R$200,00<br>
item 2 R$1.000,00<br>
item 3 R$499,00<br>
item 4 R$800,00<br>
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo que eu estava tentando fazer, porém não estava retornando nada, muito obrigado!

Comment: Por nada man. Legal que tenha ajudado!

Comment: Leandro, uma dúvida, como que eu faço para incluir na lista o nome do item, por exemplo, name="Almofada" então na lista ficaria Almofada - R$800

Comment: Deste jeito que o código esta não da para ligar cada label com os inputs selecionados. O que dá para vc fazer e resolve é colocar a descrição tipo **almofada** dentro do value do input no Html.

Comment: então mas quando eu coloco string dentro do value, quando eu somo todos os valores da erro

Comment: Certo, entendi man. Espera aí um pouco que já resolvo, estou fora, mas já consigo um computador para arrumar ;)

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76679/discussion-between-jvs-correa-and-leandro).

Comment: Opa, tava saindo já, mas, voltei rápidinho. Vou rever o código aqui e colocar a resolução só um instante.

Comment: Minha única dificuldade agora é isso, colocar string antes do value, para conseguir somar todos os valores sem dar erro :)

Comment: Blza man! Funcionando.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o seguinte seletor para pegar todos os checkboxes que estiverem selecionados:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked')
```

Abaixo, um exemplo com o seu código. Ao clicar no checkbox, ele seleciona/deseleciona e lista todos os que estão selecionados.

```js
// click nos checkbox
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
  console.log("\n");
  // seleciona todos checkboxes checados
  $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
    // escreve no console
    console.log($(this).val() + ' ');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" id="list-lugar">
  <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">-</option>
  <option value="200">1 Shopping</option>
  <option value="200">2 Shopping</option>
  <option value="100">3 Shopping</option>
  <option value="100">4 Plaza</option>
  <option value="100">5 Shopping</option>
  <option value="100">6 Plaza</option>
</select><br><br>

<input id="add-buffet" type="checkbox" value="1000" />
<label>Buffet</label><br>
<input id="add-decoracao" type="checkbox" value="499" />
<label>Decoração</label><br>
<input id="add-foto" type="checkbox" value="800" />
<label>Foto</label><br><br>

<label>Lista</label><br><br>
item 1 R$200,00<br>
item 2 R$1.000,00<br>
item 3 R$499,00<br>
item 4 R$800,00<br>
```

A partir daqui você pode fazer o que quiser com os valores selecionados, só mudar o código dentro do `each`

Comment: Entendi!! Desculpa a pergunta, não conheço nada de javascript, e para pegar o valor das option e checkbox e apresentar em uma div por exemplo? É facil fazer isso?

Comment: Pode perguntar, participamos aqui pra nos ajudar... antes do `each`, cria uma variável, `resultado`por exemplo... depois cria o `div` com `id='resultado'` por exemplo.. no código que coloquei, no lugar do `console.log` você pode acumular os valores numa variável, assim: `resultado += "Valor: " + $(this).val() + "<br /">;`  Depois do `each` só jogar a variável no `div`:  `$('#resultado').html(resultado);` e vai aparecer os valores selecionados na `div`

Answer (score 0):

Segue uma alternativa com o *VanillaJS* (*JavaScript* Puro)

```js
/* Captura todos os elementos do tipo checkbox */
const cb = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=\"checkbox\"]")

/* Adiciona o evento "analyzeCheckBox" no elemento */
cb.forEach( checkbox => {
  checkbox.addEventListener("change", analyzeCheckBox)
})

/* Função para verificar quais checkbox estão marcados */
function analyzeCheckBox() {

  /* Limpa o console */
  console.clear()
  
  cb.forEach( checkbox => {
  
    let text = ` ${checkbox.nextElementSibling.textContent}, cujo valor é ${checkbox.getAttribute("value")}, está `
  
    /* Verifica se o elemento está marcado */
    if (checkbox.checked) {
      console.log(text, "marcado")
    } else {
      console.log(text, "desmarcado")
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<input id="add-buffet" type="checkbox" value="1000" />
<label>Buffet</label><br>
<input id="add-decoracao" type="checkbox" value="499" />
<label>Decoração</label><br>
<input id="add-foto" type="checkbox" value="800" />
<label>Foto</label><br><br>
```